# Firebase returns null value for a particular child even if it exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class ComRec which stores certain commission values. In the calculator I input some values and perform some operations then store it under particular user in firebase. Then I create a pdf table with the values from ComRec object. But my problem is the member "koil" shows the value null even if it is present in the ComRec object.

```
public class ComRec {
private Double freeRation;
private Double npnsRice;
private Double npsRice;
private Double phhRice;
private Double aayRice;
private Double npnsWheat;
private Double phhWheat;
private Double aayWheat;
private Double atta;
private Double total;
private Double koil;
private Double sugar;
private Double totalCommission;

public ComRec(){

}

public ComRec(Double freeRation, Double npnsRice, Double npsRice, Double phhRice, Double aayRice, Double npnsWheat, Double phhWheat, Double aayWheat, Double atta, Double total, Double koil, Double sugar , Double totalCommission) {
    this.freeRation = freeRation;
    this.npnsRice = npnsRice;
    this.npsRice = npsRice;
    this.phhRice = phhRice;
    this.aayRice = aayRice;
    this.npnsWheat = npnsWheat;
    this.phhWheat = phhWheat;
    this.aayWheat = aayWheat;
    this.atta = atta;
    this.total = total;
    this.koil = koil;
    this.sugar = sugar;
    this.totalCommission = totalCommission;

}
```

User class

```
public class User {
private String UID;
private String ardNo;
private String email;
private String serialKey;
private String taluk;
private ComRec C;

public User(){

}

public User(String UID, String ardNo, String email, String serialKey,String taluk) {
    this.UID = UID;
    this.ardNo = ardNo;
    this.email = email;
    this.serialKey = serialKey;
    this.taluk = taluk;
    this.C = null;
}
public User(String UID, String ardNo, String email, String serialKey,String taluk,ComRec C) {
    this.UID = UID;
    this.ardNo = ardNo;
    this.email = email;
    this.serialKey = serialKey;
    this.taluk = taluk;
    this.C = C;
}

public String getUID() {
    return UID;
}

public void setUID(String UID) {
    this.UID = UID;
}

public String getArdNo() {
    return ardNo;
}

public void setArdNo(String ardNo) {
    this.ardNo = ardNo;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSerialKey() {
    return serialKey;
}

public void setSerialKey(String serialKey) {
    this.serialKey = serialKey;
}

public String getTaluk() {
    return taluk;
}

public void setTaluk(String taluk) {
    this.taluk = taluk;
}

public ComRec getComRec() {
    return C;
}

public void setComRec(ComRec c) {
    C = c;
}
```

}

This is my firebase data, You can see koil = 172.5:

[image: 2]

All the other members gives correct value but koil

[image: 1]

This is how initialise ComRec object by taking it from User class

[image: 3]

Comment: add your `User` class code

Comment: Is that the Key of a user ? or you are just using the `push()` when inserting the data?

Comment: Put all the code inside the Handler in onDataChange method. The problem is that the code inside Handler is running before the data was fetched by onDataChange method.

Comment: @nee17 yeah I tried that too but it doesn't work.I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @AliAhsan Hi Ali, I just added my User class here.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your database structure you can use this to get the Koil

```
  DatabaseReference reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
    reff.child(user.getUid()).child("comRec").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ComRec com = snapshot.getValue(ComRec.class);
                Double Koil = com.getkoil();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: getKoil() method wasn't working for some reason and I fixed it .Thank you for the help